# How to Make Section based UICollectionVIew in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uicollectionview

I am Developing Section based UICollection view something like section based UITablview.but each section have different number of data. but my issue is that it contain the similar data for every section.

Here is Code :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //registering class for cell reusing
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell"];

    //registering class for view reusing
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[SupplementaryView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"SupplementaryView"];

   NSDictionary *animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
                @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
                @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
                @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
                @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
                @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],
                @"K" : @[@"Koala"],
                @"L" : @[@"Lion", @"Llama"],
                @"M" : @[@"Manatus", @"Meerkat"],
                @"P" : @[@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear"],
                @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
                @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
                @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
                @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};

  NSArray*  animalSectionTitles = [[animals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = @"Hello";
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
           return [animals count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return [animalSectionTitles count];

}

-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SupplementaryView *supplementaryView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"SupplementaryView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader){
        supplementaryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        supplementaryView.label.text = @"Header";
    }
    else{

    }

    return supplementaryView;
}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return CGSizeMake(500, 50);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could help you.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {



int i=0;

for (NSDictionary *item in animals) {


    if (section==i) {
        NSArray *lala=[animals objectForKey:item];

        NSLog(@"%d",lala.count);

        return lala.count;
    }


    i++;


}



}
```

Comment: i don't want to use if else  its become static i want to make dynamic .

Comment: @Rushabh i edited this to make it more global.Now maybe it is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
           return [animals count];
}
```

This method asks how many cells there are in one specific section. As you return here always the same value there will always be the same amount of cells in your sections.